# Sending POST data with a mongodb operator

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to send a block of JSON to this nodejs app that upserts that json into a mongodb. The nodejs app works for inserting and updating without mongodb operators but the problem is that I need to use the $addToSet operator to update an array of values in my collection.

This is what my JSON data looks like, it's what I'm trying to POST to the site. It uses $addToSet & $each:

```
{$addToSet:{"Data":{$each:[{"ID":"10","RandNum":"45"},{"ID":"11","RandNum":"1"},{"ID":"12","RandNum":"3"}]}}
```

I've also tried using this:

```
"{$addToSet: {\"Data\": {$each: [{\"ID\":\"10\",\"RandNum\":\"45\"},{\"ID\":\"11\",\"RandNum\":\"1\"},{\"ID\":\"12\",\"RandNum\":\"45\"}]}}"
```

Right now, I'm just trying to POST it using Fiddler. This is the error I am getting:

```
226 Error: invalid json at Object.exports.error 
(/home/dsi-user/WVS-Dev/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13) at 
/home/dsi-user/WVS-Dev/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:73:69 at
```

IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/dsi-user/WVS-Dev/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:109:7) at 
    IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16) at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17) at 
    _stream_readable.js:920:16 at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13) 0

For some reason, it doesn't seem to like the $ that's needed to update the document in my collection. I wonder if I am missing something or not encoding it correctly. I'm not sure.

Comment: Unless you don't care that the data model can be completely changed, I'd recommend you wrap this type of logic into a web service call and not allow direct setting/updates of documents through the update document.

Comment: I have to allow direct updating, it's what I was told to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the fieldnames that start with $ in quotes too:

```
{"$addToSet":{"Data":{"$each":[{"ID":"10","RandNum":"45"},{"ID":"11","RandNum":"1"},{"ID":"12","RandNum":"3"}]}}
```

Comment: That worked. Now I'm getting an error about content-length which I know how to fix! So I am all set. Thanks!